# Inexplicable (to me) clang-format space before 'new' keyword

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

After running clang-format on this

```
- (instancetype)init;
+ (instancetype)new;
```

I get this:

```
- (instancetype)init;
+ (instancetype) new;
```

How can I prevent that space between `)` and `new` from spawning?

My `.clang-format` looks like this:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
ColumnLimit: 100
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
PointerBindsToType: false
```

Comment: Completely random guess;   is it treating `new` like a `C++` keyword and using whatever rule is applicable therein?

Comment: genius, is probably something related. But I cannot find anything about that in the style options. Only about `ControlStatements` and `template` keyword :/

Comment: I think `new` in C++ is generally considered to be an operator, maybe you can find a setting with that info?